# Get XML file from url to Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem to get .xml data from website and parse to android application, i have try many suggestion but never work. It works fine when i open file in assets folder, but when i try to get from url, it show nothing

This is my Activity Class

```
package com.android.baliweather;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;  
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Prakiraan extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ListView listView;
private TextView judul;
private String URL_MAIN = "http://localhost/android/propinsi_17_1.xml";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prakiraan_cuaca);
    judul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menu1);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    bindDataToListing();
}

private void bindDataToListing() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/android/propinsi_17_1.xml");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        //URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();  
        //HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
        //InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
        SAXParserFactory saxparser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = saxparser.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();
        XMLParser pc = new XMLParser();
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(pc);
        //InputStream is = getAssets().open("propinsi_17_1.xml");
        //InputStream is = new URL(URL_MAIN).openStream();
        xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(connection.getInputStream()));
        BindingData bindingData = new BindingData(this, pc.kota, pc.cuaca, pc.suhuMin, pc.suhuMax, pc.kelembapanMin, pc.kelembapanMax, pc.kecepatanAngin, pc.arahAngin);
        listView.setAdapter(bindingData);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

I think the problem only on this class, but i have no idea which one. Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: Is it possible to dowload file to disk given an xml (from a URL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798651/android-is-it-possible-to-dowload-file-to-disk-given-an-xml-from-a-url)

Comment: many said that it is possible, check this http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

Comment: first of all Your directly using local host that will not work. Use `10.0.2.2` instead of localhost then check. for more detail visit here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` - you're trying to do time-heavy task in a UI thread and the system is preventing you from doing it (you can possibly see this in your logcat). You can implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in order to do it in the background thread.

It may also be that you forgot to add the permission in a manifest file - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`